# Conversion error for data type varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, sql-server-2017

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBarData](
    @userId INT,
    @unitIds VARCHAR(255),
    @language NVARCHAR(2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT tn.rid AS newsRid
    FROM tNews tn
    LEFT JOIN tNewsLog tnl ON tn.rid = tnl.newsId AND tnl.userId = @userId
    WHERE 
        tn.unitId IN (@unitIds)
        AND (tn.validTo IS NULL OR tn.validTo > GETDATE())
        AND ((tn.priority = 1 AND (tnl.inInfoList = 1 OR tnl.inInfoList IS NULL)) OR tn.priority = 2)
    ORDER BY tn.priority DESC, shortDescription ASC;
END
```

```
-- Execute the stored procedure with the parameters
EXEC GetNewsOverviewBarData 89567, '1,3,5,7', 'en' ;
```

error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,3,5,7' to data type int.

Comment: You can't pass an array like that.  You might consider casting `tn.unitId` to string and using `FIND_IN_SET` to search your string parameter.

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT @@version;` and report what it says.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116434/200032

Comment: Timroberts-> FIND_IN_SET does not exists as a default function in dbeaver. You have to create one. However, adding this in my query, does the job
CHARINDEX('','' + CAST(tn.unitId AS VARCHAR(10)) + '','', '','' + @unitIds + '','') > 0

Comment: @BillKarwin 

Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: If you are using SQL Server then remove the tag `mysql` and add `sqlserver`.

Comment: I have applied the edits to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to use a `VARCHAR` parameter (`@unitIds`) in the `IN` clause of your SQL query, which expects a list of integers.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBarData](
    @userId INT,
    @unitIds VARCHAR(255),
    @language NVARCHAR(2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UnitIdTable TABLE (UnitId INT);

    INSERT INTO @UnitIdTable
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) AS UnitId
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@unitIds, ',');

    SELECT tn.rid AS newsRid
    FROM tNews tn
    LEFT JOIN tNewsLog tnl ON tn.rid = tnl.newsId AND tnl.userId = @userId
    WHERE 
        tn.unitId IN (SELECT UnitId FROM @UnitIdTable)
        AND (tn.validTo IS NULL OR tn.validTo > GETDATE())
        AND ((tn.priority = 1 AND (tnl.inInfoList = 1 OR tnl.inInfoList IS NULL)) OR tn.priority = 2)
    ORDER BY tn.priority DESC, shortDescription ASC;
END
```